# How is the compiler able to handle indirect method type deduction?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When I have always worked with templates I have always made a single file called Test.h. This would include a templated signatures, and definitions associated with it.

I started working with templated member functions, and noticed I am able to separate declaration vs implementation if a member calls the templated method. How is this possible because I thought the compiler needed to generate the templated methods?

Original example of where compilation fails...

---

MyTest.h

```
class MyTest
{
 public:
     MyTest();
     ~MyTest();
    template <typename T>
    int testMethod(T&& var);
};
```

MyTest.cpp

```
#include "MyTest.h"

MyTest::MyTest()
{

};

MyTest::~MyTest()
{

};

template <typename T>
int MyTest::testMethod(T&& var)
{
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MyTest.h"
int main()
{
    MyTest testClass;
    testClass.testMethod(1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

However this works when I have another member call it, and it's not directly accessed by main.

---

MyTest.h

```
class MyTest
{
 private:
    template <typename T>
    int testMethod(T&& var);
 public:
     MyTest();
     ~MyTest();
    void testMethod2();
};
```

MyTest.cpp

```
#include "MyTest.h"

MyTest::MyTest()
{

};

MyTest::~MyTest()
{

};

template <typename T>
int MyTest::testMethod(T&& var)
{
    return 0;
}

void MyTest::testMethod2()
{
    testMethod(5);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MyTest.h"
int main()
{
    MyTest testClass;
    testClass.testMethod2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, at the point where you instantiate the templated method, does the translation unit have a definition for that function available?

Comment: Ah okay, that's a great way to think about it. Thank you!